# loop minus one string from list in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a list of strings (a_001 a_002 a_003 ect.) which I would like to use in a command minus one string each time it is run. That is, I would like to run a loop where the first time a_002 and a_003 are included followed by a_001 & a_003 and then a_001 and a_002. Can this be set up in bash?

Comment: Thanks to provide sample output

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problem? For example, an outline of the code you're aiming for would help clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a set of strings `S`, you want to use `S - {x}` for each `x` in `S`.

Here's one way:

```
 S=( a_001 a_002 a_003 )
 set -- "${S[@]}"
 for x; do
     shift                          # Removes x from the positional arguments
     echo "Use $@ without $x"       # Some action involving `S - {x}`
     set -- "$@" "$x"               # Put x back on the end, put
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

x=( a_001 a_002 a_003 )

set -- "${x[@]}"

while [[ $@ ]]; do
    echo "command $@"
    shift
done
```

Is it what you expected ?

### Output

```
command a_001 a_002 a_003
command a_002 a_003
command a_003
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the subjects to be removed and added back on subsequent loops. Like a leave-one-out type method. I think the below response is what I'm looking for.